# Using EXTENT SIZE + NEXT SIZE for TEMP tables will impact performance in informix DB?

Tags: informix, create-table, temp-tables

I want to know if there is any performance impact if using `EXTENT SIZE, NEXT SIZE` while creating temp tables in Informix DB.

Answer (score 1):

That smells like premature optimization to me. In 20 years of writing Informix SQL, I don't think I've ever found the need to set `EXTENT SIZE` or `NEXT SIZE` on an explicitly created TEMP table. Assuming you have DBSpaces on decent speed disks allocated for temporary tables, there's aren't too many performance tuning options. Temporary tables aren't logged in the first place, so there's not a lot of overhead.

The only theoretical benefit in declaring an `EXTENT SIZE` might be to ensure there was sufficient TEMP space available *before* commencing a long running query, but it seems like a very blunt instrument. It does not guarantee that you won't run out of space anyway, and simultaneously allocates space that is unavailable to other queries. As I said, classic example of premature optimization.

Long story short, the answer is no, there's no performance benefit in setting the size attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Performance impact is more likely for **not** sizing the temp table with care - particularly if your dbspacetemp configuration spans multiple dbspaces and you have lots of user sessions creating similar tables from an application (as opposed to a one-off SQL).

Too many extents can slow things down - either through the temp table rapidly growing bigger than the default temp table size, or from what you think being a smaller temp table being round-robin distributed to each space in the dbspacetemp list.  Shrinking the list of dbspaces in the dbspacetemp might help.